# Blur Fixed Header

Tags: css, header, fixed

i have a little Question. I have an fixed Header in my Website but i have one problem. I would like to Blur the Background of the Fixed Header only the background not the Buttons on it.

My Header.php :

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#header{
    background-color: #F9F6F3;
 pacity: 0.00;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <header id="fh5co-header" role="banner">
   <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle dark"><i></i></a>
    <div id="fh5co-logo"><a href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" height="50" width="95" alt="Hello World"></a></div>
    <nav id="fh5co-main-nav" role="navigation">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
      <li class="has-sub">
       <div class="drop-down-menu">
        <a href="scl">Cool</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-wrap">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Button1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Button2+n</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

The Question now how i can blur the Background from the Header in the css ?

Answer (score 0):

add this to html header

```
 <div class="background-image"></div>
```

put this in your style tags

```
header{position: relative;
}
header .background-image {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
 filter: blur(5px);}
```

Comment: Not function :(   I have edit my css to : *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#header{
    background-color: #F9F6F3;
 pacity: 0.00;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}header{position: relative;
}
header .background-image {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
 filter: blur(5px);}

Comment: @M.Martin did you insert <div class="background-image"></div> in html